# How to add order delivery date and time in WooCommerce order?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

> Currently i am working on a REST API for place order and i have
>   created order using following code.

```
<?php
$order = wc_create_order(array('customer_id' => $user_id));

  $billing_addre = array(
        'first_name' => $_POST['f_name'],
        'last_name'  => $_POST['l_name'],
        'company'    => '',
        'email'      => $_POST['email'],
        'phone'      => $_POST['phone'],
        'address_1'  => $_POST['address'],
        'address_2'  => '', 
        'city'       => $_POST['city'],
        'state'      => $_POST['state'],
        'postcode'   => $_POST['p_code'],
        'country'    => $_POST['country']
    );

    $order->set_address( $billing_addre, 'billing' );

?>
```

> it's working good but i would like to add order delivery date and time
>   during create order, i added it by using custom field like

```
<?php
 update_post_meta( $order->id, 'delivery_date',  $_REQUEST["delivery_date"] );
?>
```

> but that is no best way,**( i don't do this by any plugin )** if anyone know better solution for this.
>
> Thank You!